# Are there any PHP code libraries with function(s) to read and parse information from CSV files?

Tags: php, csv

I am looking for some routines that will read and parse CSV files.  I have written some code to do this, but the data files I download are not always evenly formatted for data extraction.  I generally have to clean up the file manually before I can run my parser.

Comment: See also [CSV Library for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341219/csv-library-for-php) and [Is there a popular and/or robust PHP CSV library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087287/is-there-a-popular-and-or-robust-php-csv-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading:

- [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)
- [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Writing:

- [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: Wow.  Well, I am embarrassed.  Who'da thunk that it was built into PHP? (not me, apparently).  Thanks much for this John.

Comment: @Sorcerer86pt `fgetcsv()` is much older and `fputcsv()` is at least from 5.1. But PHP5.3 should be used nowadays anyway ;)