# Is there a library that can write an RFC 4180 CSV file with PHP?

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv, rfc4180

I am aware of fputcsv, but according to [this "wontfix" bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50686) fputcsv does not correctly escape input, and its behavior will not be fixed for compatibility reasons.  I would prefer an implementation that is compliant with [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) so Excel and LibreOffice can open it in all cases.

I've tried googling for a library that does this correctly, but there doesn't seem to be a consensus on a decent third party library, instead commonly suggesting the defective fputcsv.  I could always roll my own, but I'd prefer not to reinvent the wheel if at all possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems that every library out there stopped development some time in 2008.  I'm not sure what's up with that.  Here seem to be the popular-ish options:

- [PEAR's File_CSV](http://pear.php.net/package/File_CSV), with zero end-user documentation, as we've come to expect from PEAR.  [This looks like the expected configuration info](http://pear.php.net/package/File_CSV/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_File__File_CSV-1.0.0alpha1FileCSV.php.html#a107), including those for separator and quote.
- [parseCSV](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php) seems sane enough
- [PHP CSV Utils](http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-utils/) is linked quite a bit, though the "new blog" hosting updates is long gone.

I can't vouch for any of these.  I happen to live in a magical land where I only need to deal with Excel-generated CSV files that will never, ever contain newlines in a field.  This lets me get away with `fgetcsv`/`fputcsv` and be blissfully ignorant of how they're broken in the real world.

Comment: I just played around with some of these libs and found that parseCSV excapes " with "" and adds quotes around entries containing commas.  PHP CSV Utils doesn't do these things.  ParseCSV is also contained in a single file, while PHP CSV Utils is in multiple files and doesn't include itself, so you need lots of require_onces in any file using it.

Comment: parseCSV currently (September 2015) has uses a lot of memory with huge files (i'm talking about 100MB+). Other than that, it's awesome.