# Cleanest way to export mysql query to CSV in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code to convert a MySQL query to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv)

What is the best and cleanest way to export mysql query to CSV (for Excel 2003 and later)? "Best" in terms of **being tested, maintained, configurable** ... so something like a (standard) **PHP library** would be the ideal solution.

It should correctly **handle enclosure, escaping, charset, cr-lf, field names in 1st row,** ... etc.

There have been couple of questions on this here at SO (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125113/php-code-to-convert-a-mysql-query-to-csv)) but none really focuses on the properties I require above.

Some ideas of mine:

- use `fputcsv`? (but **charset, escaping and cr-lf** seemingly **cannot be set**!)
- extract some code from phpmyadmin...?
- `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE` doesn't work at my server (access denied)
- `system("mysqldump ...")` is not possible (safe mode hosting)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not quite sure what it is you want. A CSV file is not an XLS file. It's simply a comma (or semi-colon) separated file. That doesn't have much to do with Excel 2003 specifically. I don't see why the "or" in my above linked `answer` wont cater for your issue? Are you looking for an out of the box solution? Like I said, it is just a CSV.. Above solution takes care of escaping and all you need to do is add "field names in 1st row"

Comment: It warms my heart to see a well formatted and researched question. You have my +1.

Comment: Thanks @Truth. I tried hard :)

Comment: @Richard, I wrote "csv for excel" because I guess there are probably nuances in the CSV formats - in PHPmyAdmin you have options CSV and "CSV for MS Excel" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say, `fputcsv` is rather limited for your requirements. Extracting from phpMyAdmin is certainly possible (here's the [export logic](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/RELEASE_4_1_7/libraries/plugins/export/ExportCsv.class.php)), but you might have more success using a dedicated library. Here are a couple of choices:

- [php-csv-utils](http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-utils/). It's lightweight, configurable and looks like it'd drop easily into most applications.
- [File_CSV](http://pear.php.net/package/File_CSV) from PEAR, lacking in documentation but at least there was a release in 2011.

Having used neither of these, I'd be reluctant to pick one but based on documentation and usability I'd go for the first one.

Additional: I've just spotted [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341219/csv-library-for-php). Charles's answer is so eerily like mine I thought I ought to link to it here!

Comment: In the end I have used [php-csv-utils](http://code.google.com/p/php-csv-utils/). Looking at the reference to the "new home" which doesn't actually work, the tool seems currently unmaintained though. But works well and perhaps needs no mtce :-)