# html form input saving the data

Tags: html, mysql, forms, excel, csv

In my submit form, the user can input five different things and submit. Currently it's writing to a txt file, and it works fine. However, the goal is to sort the data by different items for a very easy read.

An example:

```
Name:
Gender:
Age:
Weight:
Haircolor:
```

The user inputs these five, and I would like to sort these by gender and age, like this:

```
John Male 34 ....
Lars Male 34 ....

Egon Male 55 ....
Sven Male 55 ....

Lisa Female 22 ....
Kim Female 22 ....
```

and so on. Would it be better to write the data to MySQL or to a .csv and format it in a spreadsheet?

Comment: Depends a bit on what you want to achieve in the end. Both aren't rocket science. Which language are you using?

Comment: The end result is a printed list of the persons arranged like a table. Im using the form on a webpage and htmlform, then saving the input to the textfile with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that... From my point of view... if you have a larger dataset, then using MySQL will be a good option for better performance...

Comment: Allright, cheers! I will look into how to do that :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't expect a lot of data - mysql isn't warranted for.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341219/csv-library-for-php) you can find some PHP CSV libraries that may help you to do what you want.

Otherwise, there are standard things like [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)/[fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

MySQL implementation would probably be very simple as well, but of course requires a working MySQL and all that comes with it :)

Comment: Thanks for the links! The requested data is from a competition signup and my brother in law dosent really know how many who will sign up, so i think i will start with looking into MySQL and from there maybe if its not that needed go to csv :-)

Comment: Let me put it this way ;) 1000 or even 10000 is a number CSV can handle. Having MySQL knowledge, at least basic one will pay off in the end :) So basically there's, in my view, no 'correct' answer to your question - just use what you're most comfortable with. MySQL will definitely be much faster with sorting, if tables are done properly, but then again, as long as you don't count in thousands, the difference will probably be barely noticeable.